# Why are there only 2 overclock options when there's supposed to be 5?

Tags: overclocking

When I check the overclock options on my RBPi 2 Model B V1.1 (BCM2709, revision a01041) with Raspbian installed through NOOBS, I only see 2 overclock options. I thought there would be around 5 options or so. Why am I only seeing 2?

[image: overclock_options_rbpi]

Answer (score 1):

> I thought there would be around 5 options or so.

There are, for the BCM2835 models (A/B/+) -- "none" plus four more.

If you look at [the source](https://github.com/asb/raspi-config/blob/master/raspi-config) for `raspi-config` (or "a" raspi-config, there are quite a few of them on github, this has the most forks but I don't know which is the most "official" since the Foundation's own github page does not have one at all), you find:

```
do_overclock() {
  whiptail --msgbox "\
Be aware that overclocking may reduce the lifetime of your
Raspberry Pi. If overclocking at a certain level causes
system instability, try a more modest overclock. Hold down
shift during boot to temporarily disable overclock.
See http://elinux.org/RPi_Overclocking for more information.\
" 20 70 1
  OVERCLOCK=$(whiptail --menu "Chose overclock preset" 20 60 10 \
    "None" "700MHz ARM, 250MHz core, 400MHz SDRAM, 0 overvolt" \
    "Modest" "800MHz ARM, 250MHz core, 400MHz SDRAM, 0 overvolt" \
    "Medium" "900MHz ARM, 250MHz core, 450MHz SDRAM, 2 overvolt" \
    "High" "950MHz ARM, 250MHz core, 450MHz SDRAM, 6 overvolt" \
    "Turbo" "1000MHz ARM, 500MHz core, 600MHz SDRAM, 6 overvolt" \
    "Pi2" "1000MHz ARM, 500MHz core, 500MHz SDRAM, 2 overvolt" \
```

Seems slightly different (perhaps yours was tailored to the Pi 2) but there's only one applicable option there other than the default.

Note you *can* try whatever you want in `config.txt`, I believe.  At some point you void the warranty though (and yes, they can determine that afterward).

Comment: Thanks. I specified the version of my rbpi. Does your answer still apply?